# How to maximize tiled window in cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon

Cinnamon has nice tile mode (win-left/right/up/down). But if window was tiled, it's hard to maximize it back on full screen if there are few tiled windows?

Is someone knew how to maximize tiled window?

Answer (score 0):

To maximize the window you can use the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f10</kbd> key combination or you can click the maximize button on the top right corner of the window.

[image: Maximize button]

Comment: It does not work if there are four snapped windows (to each screen quadrant). To check this open four windows and use Ctrl-Win-arrow key to snap them to different corners. Alt-F10 will expand window to half of the screen. Original question was not 'how to maximize window', but 'how to maximize snapped window'.